# Ratio for comparison between groups and correlation analyses

Tags: hypothesis-testing, data-transformation

I'm trying to compare two groups on their ratio between two scores and then investigate the correlation of this ratio for each participant with scores obtained  on other tests. What would be an appropriate way of calculating this ratio and what statistical test would I then use to see if there is a significant difference between the groups?

NB: some of the scores involved = 0

```
 personID c_world_right c_world_left group  
<int>         <int>     <int> <chr>  
1          3489         3945 control
2          3754         3952 patient
3          5154         2386 control
4          4173         4183 patient
6          2919         2617 control
7          4109         1270 patient
```